# How can I get H.264 support?

Tags: html5

Canonical Limited is shown as a licensee of H.264. I am interested in being able to play H.264 video online when using the Chrome web-browser in Ubuntu (and in the future on Firefox when Firefox supports H.264).

Is H.264 support enabled on self-installs of Ubuntu? If not, is there some way I can buy H.264 support for my Ubuntu install? Assume a scenario where I self-installed Ubuntu on a computer that came pre-installed with Windows OS. I'd like to know any and all options available to me for getting H.264 to work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: I investigated this issue as well. For Chrome h.264 is no problem as it is builtin by now, but Firefox has plans to support it via gstreamer see http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM5NzU. So with nightly build (8/Aug/2013) you should set the perference: `media.gstreamer.enabled` to true and install proper codecs for gstreamer. I have not tested this, as nightly build are very unstable.

Answer (score 13):

The **ubuntu-restricted-extras** has all the multimedia decoding packages in and working for me on the decoding end.  And chromium automatically used the ffmpeg plug-in.

If there are packages in restricted-extras you are sure you don't want you could try just
**chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra** from the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

Just to be sure it makes it in to chromium and you don't just get the codec.

Comment: Will only work for chromium (chrome has it builtin by now) and not for Firefox.

Comment: Then firefox should have been built properly and if it's a built-in in chrome (and you're using it), then you should be comfortable building chrome from sources or using a binary updater.  Yossile's answer is equally correct for things that link against the library itself, but you can't have ffmpeg-extra without x264.  That being so, my answer sort of subsumes his by being more general and including chromium as well.

Comment: well, I didn't want to offend you or your answer, I just wanted to point out whats about Firefox in that case.

Answer (score 8):

You can get H.264 encoder by installing the **x264** package with the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x264
```

Comment: Definitely correct for getting h264 decoding installed, I'm just unsure whether it will get it in to chromium by itself.

Comment: Chrome (as opposed to chromium) support H.264. So assuming x264 package installs H.264 support, this should be it. Would "buying" a commercial H.264 support package give any advantages over installing the x264 package?

Comment: @Chad--24216 I believe differences are in licensing so that if someone needs it for purposes outside of the GNU-GPL it requires the commercial version.

Comment: Normally one has to pay royalties for a h264 license because she wants to distribute a video commercially, and not for decoding it for playback, as far as I know. Why would you want to use another codec? Lower CPU usage?

Comment: Just to make it clear, will not work for Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, I'm using Firefox Nightly (27.0a1 (2013-10-24)) on Ubuntu 13.10.
I made the change on the flag media.gstreamer.enabled to true.
You also need to install the package gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg.

You can check if you have h.264 enabled in this page: http://www.youtube.com/html5

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 14.04 the package `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` is not available anymore. See the bug report at [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/+bug/1275556).

Web Upd8 posted a workaround to [install the gstreamer](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/get-firefox-and-phonon-gstreamer-to.html) package using a ppa:

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
> ```

Comment: P.S. This is only a temp solution, as of Firefox 30, [support for GStreamer1.0 will be available](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/30.0a2/auroranotes/). Which is available in the default repositories 14.04. So there will be non need to add a PPA.

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0 ffmpeg
```

The MP4 video can be played now.